# How to keep leading zeros when downloading csv file in Interactive Report (Oracle Apex)

Tags: oracle-apex, export-to-csv

I am working on a project that requires me to download a csv file from an interactive report in Oracle Apex, some of the columns, however include leading zeros for some IDs and when I do the download the leading zeros are removed. I know Excel does that but is there anyway I can do something from Apex to override that behavior and make sure I get to keep the leading zeros when downloading the csv file?

Comment: Try to concatenate a single quote at the beginning of that string. For example, if ID = 0123, then `select chr(39) || id, ... from your_Table` and see what happens.

Comment: Hi, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This works for interactive reports but not interactive grids.
In your query when it is being downloaded as a CSV wrap it so
it is "=id"

```
   select
     CASE
     WHEN instr(nvl(:REQUEST, '1'), 'CSV') != 0 THEN
      '="' || id || '"'
     ELSE
      id
   END
```